# Can PDF file content stream refer to the stream in resource?

Tags: pdf, stream, resources

One of PDF page's content stream is as follows:  **`q Q q Q q /Fm1 Do Q`**

What does it mean by `/Fm1`? Is it any standard format? Do we always need to search in resources XObject stream?

Right now `/Fm1` entry is there in /Resources-> /XObject -> /Fm1.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

`/Fm1` refers to a named resource.

PDF consumers look up the dictionary of named resources attached to the page (or Form XObject or other compound object -- in any event: the object with which the stream is associated).

See the **[PDF 1.7 Reference, page 89, Section 7.8 *"Content Streams and Resources"*](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/ISO32000/PDF32000-Adobe.pdf#page=89)**.

Comment: Thanks for quick help. We need to look at "Do" operator for searching named resources (Form-XObject/Image/Postscript), I was interested in Form XObject here, Thanks :)